# xml transformation using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, soap, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to do SOAP to XML transformation in XSLT 2.0, this is the source xml:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xi="http://www.xcdm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <xi:root>
        <xmlHeader>
            <timestamp>1232135468</timestamp>
            <source>xds unit</source>
        </xmlHeader>
        <xmlBody>
            <method>create</method>
            <customer>
                <custA>VOC-Prov</custA>
                <custB>vocprov</custB>
            </customer>
            <Item>
                <subElmt1>12345</subElmt1>
                <subElmt2>534321</subElmt2>
            </Item>
        </xmlBody>
    </xi:root>
</soapenv:Body>
```

`

I have been looking for days for a way to transform the structure using XSLT 2.0 so that the output will structured by this one :

```
    <customer version="1.0">
    <custA>VOC-Prov</custA>
    <custB>vocprov</custB>
        <Item name="constName" method="value from the  method element (create)">
        <Attribute name="subElmt1">value of subElmt1 element</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="subElmt2">534321</Attribute>
    </Item>
</customer>
```

1. How can i Concat the method value as attribute in the requested xml result ?
2. What is the best way to implement xslt that convert element to attribute     that match this xml hirarchiel  ?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: a lot of things :-(  starting with concat the method value as attribute at the requested xml result

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me. Next time, please post your attempt so that we can fix your mistakes instead of writing your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been looking for days for a way to transform the structure

Not sure why you're having such trouble with this, as it seems like a relatively easy task:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <customer version="1.0">
        <xsl:variable name="body" select="//xmlBody" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$body/customer/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        <Item name="constName" method="{$body/method}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$body/Item/*">
                <Attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </Attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Item>
    </customer>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: WOW , that was fast... this was very helpful for me as case study for the next time.